# MongoDb constraint allowing only one entry in collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, constraints, document

Can I make a constraint to prevent more than one document appearing in a collection?  The collection will store the version of the database structures

In SQL I would have put a check constraint on the table that checks the count of rows in the table is less than 2

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way would be using [User-Defined Roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-user-defined-roles/#user-defined-roles) to provide [Collection-Level Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/). You can create a document with an innitial `database_version` and posteriorly assign to your user a role that restricts the access to the collection to only **find** and **update** documents.

P.S.:While searching for a solution you may have come across a possible alternative called [Capped Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/). It won't work in your case as Capped Collections restrict updates if the updates result in increased document size.